# omission of the second "that"

Tags: optional-that

Can the second "that" be omitted in the following?

> My teacher tells me that there is not much time and **that** I should study hard.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be omitted. In this case, it probably does not make it ambiguous to omit it, but sometimes it can do, and then it is clearer to repeat *that*.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not omit the second "that". It adds to the point about time with a reference to the previous point by your teacher. It also identifies it is about your teacher's views and not your own view to study hard.

Overall Colin Fine's answer is correct as well. However Colin correctly pointed out about possible ambiguity in the sentence without the second "that". As there are three ideas in this sentence they should be clearly separated with a second "that". In this way your teacher's clause is linked with the clauses of your teachers' two subsequent and separate ideas.

Sources Used:

1. [Repetition of the second ' that' after and](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/repetition-of-the-second-that-after-and.2442083/) "https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/repetition-of-the-second-that-after-and.2442083/".
2. [Repetition Of 'That'?](https://www.englishforums.com/English/RepetitionOfThat/cjjzg/post.htm) "https://www.englishforums.com/English/RepetitionOfThat/cjjzg/post.htm".

Comment: Welcome to the site Nathan! So you know, we don't deal in personal opinions here, just fact-based answers. If we do occasionally depart into opinion, it's done tangentially, after having answered the actual question. The question was about whether it was possible to omit it. The answer is yes.